# Casting compatible but different slices of maps

Tags: go

I'm working with two libraries, and one defines a type:

```
type Attrs map[string]string
```

while the other defines:

```
type StringMap map[string]string
```

A function from the first library returns an `[]Attrs`, and struct required by the other has a field as `[]StringMap` which needs to be set. Attempting to either use a simple assignment, or a cast in the form of `([]StringMap)(attrs)`, just results in an error:

```
./wscmd.go:8:22: cannot convert attrs (type []mpd.Attrs) to type []StringMap
```

So, how can those be bridged?

**Edit:** Ok, apparently this is a language limitation (booo-hooo). Can it be stepped aside with unsafe pointers?

Comment: why not just iterate over attr and put the data into stringmap?

Comment: Performance reasons, those are potentially huge. And the structures are basically the same, there has to be a way of just using them.

Comment: Type aliases could have helped.

Comment: "Ok, apparently this is a language limitation (booo-hooo). Can it be stepped aside with unsafe pointers?" -- this is a terrible question.  Just use a loop.

Comment: Uhm, that's a completely inappropriate response and an unwarranted downvote. Just use a loop? For assigning two containers defined exactly the same? I think it's fair to call it a language limitation because other practical languages allow it, which makes, comparing them by *this particular feature*, Go more limited. Consider this valid C++ code: https://gist.github.com/ebit-ivoras/170fa97131b5d105aaaa7fa94cae11ee .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but it circumvents Go's type safety, which can lead to trouble depending on implementation type.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    type Attrs map[string]string
    type StringMap map[string]string
    a := Attrs{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
    b := Attrs{"key3": "val3", "key4": "val4"}

    attrs := []Attrs{a, b}

    // This is what you're asking for, keep in mind this circumvents the type safety provided by go

    sh := *(*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&attrs))
    unsafeStrMaps := *(*[]StringMap)(unsafe.Pointer(&sh))
    fmt.Println(unsafeStrMaps)

    // This would be the preferred way of casting the array

    strMaps := []StringMap{}
    for _, v := range attrs {
        strMaps = append(strMaps, StringMap(v))
    }

    fmt.Println(strMaps)
}
```

It is much better for type safety to just iterate the `[]Attrs` slice and append to a `[]StringMap`.